# custom checklist / task list, stuck on multiple items

Tags: java, android

dev working on this android app died and left me with the source code to finish it on my own but I'm getting hung up on this, can anyone help?

This is a checklist that's included in the app for user to check off certain things. But I'm getting hung up on where in the code to add multiple items. It just runs on a loop with 50 checklist items that say "Do ETC", instead I need it to have 50 DIFFERENT items that I put in.

Here's the part I'm getting hung up on I think

```
    //TODO change here for your custom checklist items
public void addDefaultTasks(Context context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setStatus(0);
        task.setIsDeleted(0);
        task.setIsDefault(1);
        task.setTaskName("Do ETC" + i);//this sthe name you will change.
        if (this.insertTask(context, task)) {
            System.out.println("Added " + task.getTaskName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you storing the items that you are trying to put in?

Comment: If you need to add in 50 different items you could perhaps create an array containing those 50 items and then inside of your for loop here you could add the array item to the index of I

Comment: I think where it says  task.setTaskName("Do ETC" + i);//this sthe name you will change  is where I'm supposed to be putting my items, but when I put them in it doesn' work